# how to solve discrete logarithm problem information requested

Tags: encryption

I have seen [your example](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61302/555) about ecdlp solver :The Problem is as follows:

$$E\backslash GF(p):y^2=x^3+17230x+22699$$

where $p=23981$, point $G$ with prime order $|G| = 109$

Alice creates a public key by selecting a private key $d<q$, public key $Q=[d]G = (3141,12767)$

Therefore;

- public information : $a,b,p,G,q,Q$
- private key : $d$

However, this curve has the following characteristic:

$\Delta= −16( 4a^3+27b^2) \bmod p =0$
That is, the discriminant is 0. and embedding degree is 2

I, however, don't understand where comes out the value  (23796,0) i.e how can I calculate it? and then the following formula equation: after which we obtain the corresponding curve
$$y^2=x^3+23426x^2$$

- is it possible for a further explanation of how you determine the point $(27396,0)$?

Comment: Is there still anything missing from the answer that keeps you from accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x,y) = -y^2 + x^3+17230x+22699$ over $\Bbb F_p$ with $p=23981$. A point on the curve is a singular point if and only if the partial derivatives are vanishes at that point. The partial derivatives are;

- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3x^2 + 17230 =0 \pmod p$ and vanishes at $x=\{185,23796\}$ found by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%203x%5E2%20%2B%2017230%20%3D0%20mod%2023981%20) or it can be found by [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -2y = 0 \pmod p$ and vanishes at $y=0$

The vanishing point $(185,0)$ is not on the curve, however, $(23796,0)$ is.

Therefore $(23796,0)$ is a singular point for the Curve.

Then we then translate the origin to this singular point $(23796,0)$, that is replace $(x,y)$ by $(x+23796,y+0$) in the equation of $E$, yielding the equation of the curve in the shifted referential:
$$y^2 = x^3 + 23426x^2$$
The rest is in [the answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61434/555) which the OP had trouble with.

Note: credit goes to @kelalaka for the better of the present answer, in particular introducing $f(x,y)$ and its partial derivatives.

Comment: We begin with the singular curve
y2=x3+17230x+22699.
This curve is singular, as can be immediately determined by its 0 discriminant. Furthermore, it has a singular point (23796,0), where both partial derivatives vanish. We translate the curve to have this singular point at (0,0) by changing thanks for your explaination.variables (x,y)↦(x−23796,y−0), after which we obtain the corresponding curve
y2=x3+23426x2,
which can be rewritten as
y2=x2(x+23426).

Comment: thanks for your explaination, after i have obtained the point of the curve, (23796,0) how can i obtain the value 23426 put in the script? how can i obtain the new equation: y2=x^3+23426^x2?

Comment: @fabio did you apply the change of variables?

Comment: @kelalaka..can you write me as i can do the change of variables please?

Comment: @fabio Actually, it was written in the answer. here [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28x%2B23796%29%5E3+%2B+17230*%28x%2B23796%29+%2B+22699++mod+23981+)

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka

Comment: @fabio: do yourself the favor of finding precisely at what step attempting that procedure with a non-singular curve fails.

Comment: @fabio: The best known method for elliptic curves of medium size are [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) and [Rubber-hose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) (with the later summarized by this [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/538/))